# python regular expression to find something in between two strings or phrases

Tags: python, regex

How can I use regex in python to capture something between two strings or phrases, and removing everything else on the line?

For example, the following is a protein sequence preceded by a one-line header.  How can I sift off "CG33289-PC" from the header below based on the stipulation that is occurs after the phrase "FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:" and before the next comma "," ?

I need to substitute the header with this simplified result "CG33289-PC" and not destroy the protein sequence (found below the header-line in all caps).

**This is what each protein sequence entry looks like - a header followed by a sequence:**

> >FBpp0293870 type=protein;loc=3L:join(21527760..21527913,21527977..21528076,21528130..21528390,21528443..21528653,21528712..21529192,21529254..21529264); ID=FBpp0293870; name=CG33289-PC; parent=FBgn0053289,FBtr0305327; dbxref=FlyBase:FBpp0293870,FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:CG33289-PC; MD5=478485a27487608aa2b6c35d39a3295c; length=405; release=r5.45; species=Dmel; 
>   MEMLKYVISDNNYSWWIKLYFAIIFALVLFVAVNLAVGIYNKWDSTPVII
>   GISSKMTPIDQIPFPTITVCNMNQAKKSKVEHLMPGSIRYAMLQKTCYKE
>   SNFSQYMDTQHRNETFSNFILDVSEKCADLIVSCIFHQQRIPCTDIFRET
>   FVDEGLCCIFNVLHPYYLYKFKSPYIRDFTSSDRFADIAVDWDPISGYPQ
>   RLPSSYYPRPGVGVGTSMGLQIVLNGHVDDYFCSSTNGQGFKILLYNPID
>   QPRMKESGLPVMIGHQTSFRIIARNVEATPSIRNIHRTKRQCIFSDEQEL
>   LFYRYYTRRNCEAECDSMFFLRLCSCIPYYLPLIYPNASVCDVFHFECLN
>   RAESQIFDLQSSQCKEFCLTSCHDLIFFPDAFSTPFSQKDVKAQTNYLTN
>   FSRAV

**This is the desired output:**

> CG33289-PC
>   MEMLKYVISDNNYSWWIKLYFAIIFALVLFVAVNLAVGIYNKWDSTPVII
>   GISSKMTPIDQIPFPTITVCNMNQAKKSKVEHLMPGSIRYAMLQKTCYKE
>   SNFSQYMDTQHRNETFSNFILDVSEKCADLIVSCIFHQQRIPCTDIFRET
>   FVDEGLCCIFNVLHPYYLYKFKSPYIRDFTSSDRFADIAVDWDPISGYPQ
>   RLPSSYYPRPGVGVGTSMGLQIVLNGHVDDYFCSSTNGQGFKILLYNPID
>   QPRMKESGLPVMIGHQTSFRIIARNVEATPSIRNIHRTKRQCIFSDEQEL
>   LFYRYYTRRNCEAECDSMFFLRLCSCIPYYLPLIYPNASVCDVFHFECLN
>   RAESQIFDLQSSQCKEFCLTSCHDLIFFPDAFSTPFSQKDVKAQTNYLTN
>   FSRAV

Comment: Can you please show what the desired output would be ?

Comment: Do you _just_ need to _find_ the annotation ID, or do you already know what the ID is and need to replace it with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regexps:

```
>>> s = """>FBpp0293870 type=protein;loc=3L:join(21527760..21527913,21527977..21528076,21528130..21528390,21528443..21528653,21528712..21529192,21529254..21529264); ID=FBpp0293870; name=CG33289-PC; parent=FBgn0053289,FBtr0305327; dbxref=FlyBase:FBpp0293870,FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:CG33289-PC; MD5=478485a27487608aa2b6c35d39a3295c; length=405; release=r5.45; species=Dmel; MEMLKYVISDNNYSWWIKLYFAIIFALVLFVAVNLAVGIYNKWDSTPVII
GISSKMTPIDQIPFPTITVCNMNQAKKSKVEHLMPGSIRYAMLQKTCYKE
SNFSQYMDTQHRNETFSNFILDVSEKCADLIVSCIFHQQRIPCTDIFRET
FVDEGLCCIFNVLHPYYLYKFKSPYIRDFTSSDRFADIAVDWDPISGYPQ
RLPSSYYPRPGVGVGTSMGLQIVLNGHVDDYFCSSTNGQGFKILLYNPID
QPRMKESGLPVMIGHQTSFRIIARNVEATPSIRNIHRTKRQCIFSDEQEL
LFYRYYTRRNCEAECDSMFFLRLCSCIPYYLPLIYPNASVCDVFHFECLN
RAESQIFDLQSSQCKEFCLTSCHDLIFFPDAFSTPFSQKDVKAQTNYLTN
FSRAV"""
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r'.*FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:([\w-]+).*;', r'\1\n', s)
CG33289-PC
 MEMLKYVISDNNYSWWIKLYFAIIFALVLFVAVNLAVGIYNKWDSTPVII
GISSKMTPIDQIPFPTITVCNMNQAKKSKVEHLMPGSIRYAMLQKTCYKE
SNFSQYMDTQHRNETFSNFILDVSEKCADLIVSCIFHQQRIPCTDIFRET
FVDEGLCCIFNVLHPYYLYKFKSPYIRDFTSSDRFADIAVDWDPISGYPQ
RLPSSYYPRPGVGVGTSMGLQIVLNGHVDDYFCSSTNGQGFKILLYNPID
QPRMKESGLPVMIGHQTSFRIIARNVEATPSIRNIHRTKRQCIFSDEQEL
LFYRYYTRRNCEAECDSMFFLRLCSCIPYYLPLIYPNASVCDVFHFECLN
RAESQIFDLQSSQCKEFCLTSCHDLIFFPDAFSTPFSQKDVKAQTNYLTN
FSRAV
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution, but this should work for you:

```
>>> fly = 'FlyBase_Annotation_IDs'
>>> repl = 'CG33289-PC'
>>> part1, part2 = protein.split(fly)
>>> part2 = part2.replace(repl, "FooBar")
>>> protein = fly.join([part1, part2])
```

assuming `FlyBase_Annotation_IDs` can only appear once in the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the format of the file, but this regex will capture the data in your example:

```
"FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:([A-Z0-9a-z-]*);"
```

Use `findall` function to get the match.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a newline after the header:

```
>>> import re
>>> protein = "..."
>>> r = re.compile(r"^.*FlyBase_Annotation_IDs:([A-Z0-9a-z-]*);.*$", re.MULTILINE)
>>> r.sub(r"\1", protein)
```

The group `([A-Z0-9a-z-]*)` in the regular expression extracts any alphanumeric character and the dash. If ids can have other characters, just add them.